# Problems in solving a non-linear system with scipy fsolve or scipy.optimize.root with Python

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

i have a question about solving a system of equations in python. 
Here i propose a case in which there are 5 equations.
the explicit system is this:

def f(x):

```
F = numpy.array([x[0]*x[2]/(1+x[0]*x[2]) + x[0]*x[3]/(1+x[0]*x[3]) + x[0]*x[4]/(1+x[0]*x[4]) -2,
     x[1]*x[2]/(1+x[1]*x[2]) + x[1]*x[3]/(1+x[1]*x[3]) + x[1]*x[4]/(1+x[1]*x[4]) - 2,
     x[0]*x[2]/(1+x[0]*x[2]) + x[1]*x[2]/(1+x[1]*x[2]) -1,
     x[0]*x[3]/(1+x[0]*x[3]) + x[1]*x[3]/(1+x[1]*x[3]) -2,
     x[0]*x[4]/(1+x[0]*x[4]) + x[1]*x[4]/(1+x[1]*x[4]) -1,])

return F
```

an alternative way that i have tried is:

```
    F = numpy.zeros(5)
    d = numpy.array([2,2])
    u = numpy.array([1,2,1])

    def f(x):
        for i in range(2):
            for k in range(3):
               F[i] += x[i]*x[k+2]/(1+x[i]*x[k+2])
            F[i] = F[i] - d[i]
        for i in range(3):
            for k in range(2):
               F[i+2] += x[i+2]*x[k]/(1+x[k]*x[i+2])
            F[i+2] = F[i+2] - u[i]
        return F
```

Now, when i try:

```
    a = [1,1,0.5,1,0,5] #initial guess
    sol = fsolve(f,a)
```

the first metod seems ok and gives the solution:

```
    array([2.63229589e+01, 2.63229589e+01, 3.79966918e-02, 2.11613301e+02,3.79966918e-02])
```

The second one instead gives the initial guess as the solution, so, apparently, nothing happens:

```
    array([1. , 1. , 0.5, 1. , 0.5])
```

I don't get why the second method doesn't work. 
I wrote the second case because the real system i have to solve has hundreds of equations with hundreds of terms (they are the result of a summation), so i can't write it explicitly. 
This case of only 5 equations is a reduced case i have tried but i still don't understand where is the problem. I think is something with the "for" iterative cycles in f(x) when i define the equations F of the system, but, again, i literally have no idea about what is wrong.

Can anyone help me?